# Jenkins and MSBuild and Copy Artifacts Plugin and proper usage for multiple projects

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

My problem boils down to this base case: our solution has two projects, A and B, which project C then includes into its build process.

When someone pushes to project A or B, Jenkins builds the project using MSBuild, archives the artifact, and then kicks off a build of C.

When C begins, it has four "Copy Artifacts" tasks that need to run: first, it copies the artifacts from A into .\A\obj\Release\, then it copies *the same artifacts* into .\A\bin\Release. Then it repeats for project B. Then it builds itself.

That's right: for each project C relies on, Copy Artifacts has to be run twice, or else MSBuild detects that something is out of date and the whole thing is built from scratch.

Is there an easier way to do this? Can I pass a parameter to MSBuild (or configure the .csproj) that says "only build this project, assume the other project binaries are up-to-date, regardless of the timestamp"? Is there a better plugin that will take care of this for me?

This is really annoying (and confusing) in our real-world case where we've got almost 20 different projects, with layered dependencies between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass BuildProjectReferences=false into MSBuild to tell it to skip auto-building references and just build the project indicated.

Comment: How did I miss that. That is probably exactly what I need.